# Check if a website is HTTP or HTTPS

Tags: php, http, https

How can I check is a website is secure with a **HTTPS** or insecure with a **HTTP** ?

Actually, my user need the enter their website like this : **domain.com**.

My system need to *ping* this domain and check if it's a **HTTPS** or a **HTTP**.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just a word of caution... Questions like yours, that do not display any sort of attempt and that lack detail will not get very much help.. if it all. I assume your using php based off of your tag...

Comment: a curl head request would work

Comment: Really depends on the protocol used and if the server enforces a specific protocol. My server for example enforces HTTPS. If you just enter `domain.com` HTTP will be used, unless the server redirects you back to `https://domain.com`.

Answer (score 2):

```
function check_https($url) {
  $ch = curl_init('https://' . $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'HEAD'); // it's a HEAD
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); // no body
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // in case of redirects
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0); // turn on if debugging
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // head only wanted
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); // we don't want to wait forever
  curl_exec($ch);
  $header = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  // var_dump($header);
  if ($header === 0) { // no ssl
    return false;
  } else { // maybe you want to check for 200
    return true;
  }
}
var_dump(check_https("google.com"));
```

Answer (score 0):

With the curl functions you can check:

- if the website talks http on port 80
- if the website talks https on port 443

But maybe it's not the same answer:

- Some server answer the "public" content over http and the "private" content over https
- Some server may answer something completely unrelated, because they choose to
- Some sever may have port 443 incorrectly configured, and answer the default website of the webserver (could be anything, not related to the request, and probably with a wrong certificate)

Answer (score -1):

cURL both http:// and https://, return the one you'd like. The user can still enter the URL without the protocol.

Comment: i would love to see how you ping the url here

Comment: Ping doesn't work using HTTP - it works with IP addresses (or domains that are converted to IP addresses). It'd be better to use cURL on port 80, and if that fails, port 443, and see which succeeds.

Comment: Clearly it wouldn't be the 'ping' you're talking about, but thanks for your helpful comment. There are plenty of http level pinging tools out there.

Comment: cURL is the solution.

Comment: "http level pinging tools" - name one?